# Convert many columns into one or two

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge data sheet that needs to be converted to examples below:

**Option 1:**

[image]

**Option 2:**

[image]

Is there a formula that I can use? NOTE: No query/VBA, rookie here!

Comment: Please add the result in your question, instead of posting pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice brainteaser, so I gave it a go:

- First we need to break up rows and columns, we need to know how many columns you are using first and get their column number. I opted to go with `=AGGREGATE` and it would like:

`=AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$C$5<>"")/($A$2:$C$5<>""))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$5),ROWS($A$2:A2))`

- Let's say we have put these numbers in column `L` for now. Second we will need to know the row number for each item using `=COUNTIFS() function. A formula would look like:

`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("L2:L"&ROW()),L2)+1`

Our result so far looks like screenshot below:

[image]

- Our third step now is to get the adres of our row and column index numbers using

`=ADDRESS(K2,L2,4,1)`

- We will need this in our fourth step to return a value using `=INDIRECT()` like so:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(K2,L2,4,1)`

- The last step returned our name, but we also want the months value. We can get that using a combination of `=INDEX()` and our column index number in a formula like below:

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$5;1;L2)`

- Now we combine everything to get the results in columns `E:F` (this might look difficult) but

Cel `E2`:
`=INDEX($A$1:$C$5,1;AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$C$5<>"")/($A$2:$C$5<>""))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$5),ROWS($A$2:A2)))`

Cel `F2`:
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()),E2)+1,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$C$5<>"")/($A$2:$C$5<>""))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$5),ROWS($A$2:A2)),4,1))`

- This is nice but what if one of your columns has empty cells at the end? Well, it will give an error for that cell on the end of your list. We can deal with this two ways; a simple `=IFERROR()` function to catch the error. But more efficient would be to prevent a calculation of such long functions through looking if we even need to do a calculation. We can use a little trick to look at how many rows are being used compared to the number of values. If smaller or equal, we need to do a calculation. A formula would look like this:

`=IF(ROWS($D$2:D2)<=COUNTA($A$2:$C$5),...Do our calculation.....,"")`

Lets include that in our final formula to put in:

`E2`:
`=IF(ROWS($D$2:D2)<=COUNTA($A$2:$C$5),INDEX($A$1:$C$5,1;AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$C$5<>"")/($A$2:$C$5<>""))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$5),ROWS($A$2:A2))),"")`

`F2`:
`=IF(ROWS($D$2:D2)<=COUNTA($A$2:$C$5),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()),E2)+1,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$C$5<>"")/($A$2:$C$5<>""))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$5),ROWS($A$2:A2)),4,1)),"")`

- Drag formulas down and our final result looks like:

[image]